# Word for using words from other languages for stylistic effect?

Tags: word-request

> We will go to the **rendez-vous** as madame demands it.

What do you call the act of using a word from another language for stylistic effect like above as seen with the word bolded in black? I am pretty confident there's such a word, but I don't have the slightest idea what it might be.

Comment: Consider [barbarism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarism_(linguistics)). As such a language can be barbarized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collectively words "borrowed" from other languages are called *"loan words"*.  Rendezvous is one such, so much so that it's an actual English word:

> **[rendezvous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rendezvous)** (n): A meeting at an agreed time and place.

There are thousands of other such words:  *barbecue, champagne, faux pas, kitsch, modus operandi, schadenfreude* and many others.

However if you mean dropping actual foreign language words or phrases into a sentence, either to sound *cosmopolitan*, or because the words just don't translate well, then there really is no single term to describe this.  For example:

> I was so angry I couldn't speak, and it wasn't until yesterday that I had ***l'esprit d'escalier***, as the French say, and thought of what would have been a perfect response.

There are various terms for what other people might think of it, such as "elegant" or "pretentious" but the practice itself is not called anything.

Answer (score 3):

A neutral description for this is "**[code-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)**"--where a person alternates between languages or dialects in a single conversation.

It can be done for stylistic purposes, as a marker of class or community, for technical reasons, to change the degree of formality, etc.

If you're looking for a word that implies that this is a little pretentious or affected, however, I'd say that "code-switching" wouldn't meet the criteria. The term by itself doesn't imply anything about the speaker's motivations for switching.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with *preciosity*:

> **preciosity** *n*
>   1. Overrefinement, as in language, taste, or style
>   2. An instance of overrefinement
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/preciosity)</sub>